# Rails nested form with uniquness condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7.

I have three models, Person, AcademicTerm, and PersonTermStatus.

```
class PersonTermStatus {
  belongs_to :academic_term
  belongs_to :person
  validates_uniquness_of :academic_term_id, :scope => :person_id
  @ ...
}

class Person {
  has_many :person_term_statuses
}
```

In a dynamic nested form for a Person record, I allow the editing of the person_term_statuses.  But I get validation errors if the user does either of the following:

1. Deletes a status and creates a new one with the same academic term in the same change.
2. Swaps the academic terms between two existing statuses.

I understand why this is happening.  In (1), the status marked for deletion is not actually deleted before validation of the new status's uniquness condition.  In (2), the uniquness condition again is applied before any changes, and it finds another record with the same academic_term.

The problem is, I can't figure a way around this. Is there a known solution?

(My nested form implmenetation is currrently using pretty much exactly the technique from RailsCast [ [Part I](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Part II](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) )

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround for this that I know of. However, you can add foreign keys to your database to enforce the uniqueness on the database side and then use the following approach.

Add a before_validation to the parent model that deletes and recreates as new records all the children. Then add a custom validation function that manually checks the children records for uniqueness based on what's in memory (rather than what's in the database).

The downsides to this approach include:

- The children don't retain the same IDs.
- The created timestamp changes.